# Are anti-adblocker scripts forbidden by Adsense's "encouraging clicks or views" policy?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies, adblock

According to Google Adsense's policy [encouraging clicks or views](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) is not allowed which is logical, but does this affect a banner that would prompt the user to disable its ad blocker?

I am using a home made script with a translucide banner, as the capture bellow show, while registering the site with Adsense, I was told it does not respect the policy (as you may know details about what is not respected is never given, but I am pretty sure everything is respected, except may be this banner)

---

[image]

Comment: @john-conde it is not allowed to post link the site?

Comment: We have a strong preference not to as it should be unnecessary if the question is written correctly. Questions shouldn't require a user to visit a site to resolve the issue and they should be well-written enough that will will assist future visitors with the same issue. Additionally, links to sites are problematic as once the issue is resolved they are no longer useful, sometimes a user will deface their question as part of their attempt to remove any reference to their site, and sometimes it is done just in an attempt to get a free link/traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware that it's not allowed due to the AdSense policy.

The reason your website was blocked should be a different one.

Without seeing your website, I can't tell you what might be the real reason.

How many articles have you published?

Comment: I have only 6 articles on the site it's probably the cause, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Yeah try again when you have 30+ or so